# polymer 1.0 unit tests - how to bind properties to a child element?

Tags: unit-testing, polymer

I created a "child" element that is used by my custom "parent" element.  My child element tag looks like this in my "parent" element:

```
<child-element fruits="{{fruits}}"></child-element>
```

fruits is an array in my "parent" element and is not a property of my "child" element.  In my "child" element I have the following:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fruits]]">
  <paper-card>[[item.flavor]]</paper-card>
</template>
```

How can I write a unit test for my "child" element to see if the dom-repeat is working?  I want to write the test directly on the "child" element without use of "parent".  I know how to write assertions against properties of the "child" element, but I don't know how to bind or pass the fruits array that it would normally listen to from the "parent", since the parent is not part of my test.  How can I feed a fruits array to my "child" element?

Once I feed it the fruits array, how can I test to see if the corresponding paper-cards were created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *do* have a `fruits` property on your child element. You set it here:

```
<child-element fruits="{{fruits}}"></child-element>
```

This says, set child-element.fruits to parent-element.fruits.

The binding here creates an (implicit) setter for `fruits` so changes can be observed:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[fruits]]">
```

You can initialize your child element using an array literal in markup:

```
<child-element fruits='[{"flavor": "apple"}, {"flavor": "blueberry"}]'>
```

Or by setting the property in JavaScript:

```
myChildEl.fruits = myFruits;
```

I think you should be able to check the cards that were created by doing something like:

```
var cards = Polymer.dom(myChildEl.root).querySelectorAll('paper-card');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set it via the property, but I couldn't set it with the array literal.  The paper-card check worked too.

Comment: Cool! 

When doing an array literal, make sure you use single quotes on the outside and double quotes on the inside (i.e., the attribute value needs to be properly quoted JSON).